# Wrapping content height on a SnackBar

Tags: android, android-support-design, snackbar

is there any way to make a SnackBar wrapping its text content?

You can look up my problem below:

[image: here]

As you can see the text ends at "contact us at...." and it should display the entire message.

Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe that snackbar by default limits you to only 2 lines.

One thing that you could try is setting the textview inside snackbar to be multiline. Like so:

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setMaxLines(5);  //set the max lines for textview to show multiple lines
```

Let me know if that works or not

Comment: 2020 solution: `snackbar.view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text).maxLines = 5`